# Filter numbers with parentheses in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, datatables, angularjs-filter

I have a json data like this

[{name:"abc", count:"(10)", {name:"xyz", count:"(20)"}, {name:"pqr", count:20}]

I bind this data using [Angular datatables](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fl-lin.github.io%2Fangular-datatables%2F&ei=tfvyVMjaOdfluQS4k4LADw&usg=AFQjCNEBuvDD8CkeY5ifNfd8g1t0U2VZFA&sig2=L2qvAviH-EBhHcXIneyM7A) and I now want to sort the `count`

column in the following manner

**UPDATE**

In descending it should be as

count

(20)

20

(10)

In ascending it should be as

count

(10)

20

(20)

I tried to achieve the same using a custom filter defined on my table as follows

```
$scope.countFilter = function(item){                    
         return parseInt(item.count.replace('(', item));        
    };
```

But it does not seem to give me the desired result.

My table looks as follows

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Name</th>
    <th>Count </th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr ng-repeat="item in items |orderBy:'countFilter'">
   <td>{{item.name}} </td>
    <td>{{item.count}} </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution that works:

Like in @Ed Hinchliffe's solution-

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items | bracketSort:<true or false>">
```

and the filter-

```
.filter('bracketSort', function() {
  return function ( inputArray, descending ) {

    return inputArray.sort( function (a, b) {     
      //replace pattern "(number)" with "-number"
      aVal = a.count.toString().replace(/\((\d+)\)/, "-$1");
      bVal = b.count.toString().replace(/\((\d+)\)/, "-$1");
      return descending ? bVal- aVal : aVal - bVal;
    });
 };
})
```

**Update**

Now that I better understand the problem, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/07yv2tnr/1/) is a solution that works with `datatables`.

```
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['brackets_nums-asc'] = function (x, y) {
  xVal = x.toString().replace(/\((\d+)\)/, "-$1");
  yVal = y.toString().replace(/\((\d+)\)/, "-$1");
  return xVal - yVal;
}

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['brackets_nums-desc'] = function (x, y) {
  xVal = x.toString().replace(/\((\d+)\)/, "-$1");
  yVal = y.toString().replace(/\((\d+)\)/, "-$1");
  return yVal - xVal;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#example').dataTable({
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bJQueryUI": true,
        "bFilter": true,
        "bRetrieve": true,
        "bStateSave": true,
        "aoColumns": [{}, {
        "sType": "brackets_nums"
    }]
  });
})
```

I removed the Angular filter because it is not necessary, so basically the only Angular thing in this solution is the use of `ng-repeat`.
But it works!

Comment: Hi. that's a good solution. I tried using it. It gives me (10), (20), 20 in ascending :( ...did you try it in an actual datatable. check this example [http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/angularWay]. You can bind the data  as done over here and check.

Comment: how did you use ascending order?

Comment: Sorry. I didn't get you. The order comes the moment i click the sort icon on the column of my datatables. Based on the result I got , I told you the order

Comment: can you link to a working jsfiddle/plunkr with your working datatable?

Comment: yes hold on i will post the link to the same over here

Comment: I couldn't find a way to customize the sorting of `datatable`. Maybe you should try a different framework? perhaps `ng-table`?

Comment: If I use ng-table, then will your solution work? How do I use your solution in ng-table. Have you tried it out using ng-table?

Comment: Can you please have a a look at this: http://blog.lysender.com/2012/06/custom-sorting-with-jquery-datatable-plugin/ and suggest something

Comment: OK, finally, using your link, I managed to use custom sorting in datatables. Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/07yv2tnr/1/

Comment: hi @yarons : there is small change in my requirement. Please check the updated order in my question. I need it to be as the one shown. Can you suggest what change needs to be done in your logic

Comment: what's the logic here? is a number with brackets slightly bigger than a number without?

Comment: I will get back to you on this soon by cross checking the logic with my project team

Answer (score 2):

You should make a custom filter to sort them, rather than passing a predicate function (which will simply include or exclude items from the array based on the return value.

Something like this would work.. It uses `array.prototype.sort` and a custom sort function.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

.filter( 'bracketSort', function() {
  return function ( inputArray ) {
    // Look for brackets
    var bracketRegex = /\(([0-9]+)\)/;
    return inputArray.sort( function (a, b) {
      var aBrackets = bracketRegex.exec(a);
      var bBrackets = bracketRegex.exec(b);
      // brackets mean a higher value
      if(aBrackets && !bBrackets) 
        return 1;
      else if (bBrackets && !aBrackets) 
        return -1;
      else if (aBrackets)
        return aBrackets[1] - bBrackets[1];
      else
        return a - b;
    });
  };
});
```

You can use it like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items | bracketSort">
```

Comment: Hi. I tried using the filter suggested by you. However it gives me (10), (20), 20 in ascending and descending its 20,  (20), (10).

Comment: So modify the filter function slightly? :)

Comment: Then you're almost there... in the code by @Ed Hinchliffe just replace `return aBrackets[1] - bBrackets[1];` with `return bBrackets[1] - aBrackets[1];`

Comment: @yarons: I did that change but still no effect. I tried printing the value of aBrackets and bBrackets in the console. They are `null` always. Why so?

Comment: why have you used variables "a" and "b"? are they assigned any values?

Comment: a and b are just the numbers being compared. They get passed as arguments to whichever function you pass to `array.sort`. Furthermore I have double checked my function and it returns [20, (10), (20)] in ascending order, so whatever you are doing subsequently must be re-ordering it.